# Как установить собранный с помощью cmake и генератора Visual Studio 2019 проект на windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, сборка, makefile

Начал сейчас писать с++ проект на Visual Studio 16 2019 + cmake (обычно пишу на linux) и понял, что знаю как на windows собрать и установить библиотеку fmt из исходников. На linux я использовал cmake генератор make а потом собирал и устанавливал через make. Как сделать тоже самое на windows (желательно в консоле, т.е. не запуская студию)?

Я знаю что есть vcpkg, но мне важно собирать и устанавить библиотеку из исходников.

Comment: "*linux я использовал cmake генератор make а потом собирал и устанавливал через make*" - обычно так делать не стоит, вместо этого необходимо делать отдельный проект установщика / упаковщика / снапшотера / <инструмента из зоопарка linux>. На windows, если речь не идет о магазинном приложении, вполне можно будет обойтись созданием пакета msi. Ни там, ни там, устанавливать получившийся артефакт через средства сборки также не стоит.

Comment: На всякий случай предложу: Если вы просто хотите писать под windows, но не обязательно в VS, то можно поставить MSYS2. Тогда сможете делать все почти как обычно (окружение почти как на linux, компиляторы те же, make есть).

Comment: @VTT Спасибо большое за совет. Можете что-то посоветовать для сборки пакетов msi?

Comment: Все необходимое идет вместе с Windows SDK, но как доп инструмент можно задействовать Wix toolkit, который позволяет описывать инсталляционную базу данных в форме xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cmake` тем и прекрасен, что позволяет абстрагироваться от низкоуровневой (если ее так можно назвать) сборки. Тобишь, если вы сгенерировали файлы сборки для `make`, то вам не обязательно (да и не рекомедуется) вызывать сам `make`. Для сборки можно воспользоваться командой:

```bsh
cmake --build .
```

А для инсталяции подойдет такая команда:

```bsh
cmake --build . --target install
```

Обратите внимание, что инсталяция, это просто цель. Таким образом можно собирать любые цели, например тесты или отдельные библиотеки.

Comment: может поделитесь за что минус в первые же секунды?

Comment: огромное спасибо, не знал что там можно.

Comment: просто интересно: а за что сдесь вообще можно поставить минус?